# Java Dependency Injection Unit Testing

Tags: java, testing, junit, dependency-injection

Can somebody make an junit test on this class?

```
public class MyApplication {
    private EmailService email = new EmailService();

    public boolean processMessages (String msg , String recipient ) {
        if (msg.length ==0 | | recipient.length ==0 ) {
            return false ;
        }
        return this.email.sendEmail (msg , recipient ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your title makes the problem clear: you are not injecting the dependency on `EmailService`. To do that, add a setter or (better) make it `final` and add it to the constructor.

That'd look like:

```
public class MyApplication {
    private final EmailService email;

    public MyApplication(EmailService email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean processMessages (String msg , String recipient ) {
        if (msg.length() == 0 || recipient.length() == 0 ) {
            return false ;
        }
        return this.email.sendEmail (msg , recipient ) ;
    }
}
```

And an appropriate test might be (using junit and mockito):

```
private MyApplication app;
private EmailService email;

@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    email = mock(EmailService.class);
    when(email.sendEmail(any(), any())).thenReturn(true);
    app = new MyApplication(email);
}

@Test
void testProcessZeroLengthMessageOrPerson() {
    assertFalse(app.processMessages("", "Person"));
    assertFalse(app.processMessages("Message", ""));
    assertFalse(app.processMessages("", ""));
}

@Test
void testProcessMessage() {
    assertTrue(app.processMessage("Message", "Person"));
    verify(email).sendEmail("Message", "Person");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution would be to instead use dependency injection. You are already familiar with the term, so I assume you're resourceful enough to find the information required in order to apply dependency injection to the class at hand (there is information for this all over the Internet -- Wikipedia, YouTube, this site and many more..).

However, given a scenario in which you wish to test this class, and are not willing or unable to change its source code and correct the violation, then if `EmailService` and `EmailService#sendEmail` are not final, you can use reflection:

```
@Test
public void testWithoutDependencyInjection() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, String> expected = new HashMap<>();
    expected.put("Dimitris Sourailidis", "Yes, you can! But you should use dependency injection instead.");
    Map<String, String> actual = new HashMap<>();

    MyApplication app = new MyApplication();
    Field emailField = MyApplication.class.getDeclaredField("email");
    emailField.setAccessible(true);
    emailField.set(app, new EmailService() {
        @Override
        public boolean sendEmail(String msg, String email) {
            actual.put(msg, email);
            return true;
        }
    });

    for (String recipient : expected.keySet()) {
        app.processMessages(recipient, expected.get(recipient));
    }

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

If they are final, then we can make a new ClassLoader which will override `EmailService` with our own class (maybe some day I'll edit this answer and provide an example of this).

While these techniques allow testing of offending classes, they make for tests that are hard to understand and maintain. I'd think twice before I add a test like one of the above into my test suite, and will consider the possibility of refactoring or replacing the class under test well before that.

Answer (score -1):

I performed tests for mail service using green mail

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("emailSenderService")
private SenderService service;

@Autowired
@Rule
public SmtpServerRule smtpServerRule;

@Test
public void send() throws IOException, MessagingException {

    final String CONTENT = Util.randomValue();

    Message message = create();

   /* ... */

    service.send(message);

    Assert.assertTrue(smtpServerRule.getMessages().stream().findFirst().isPresent());

    String messageContent = String.valueOf(smtpServerRule.getMessages().stream().findFirst().get().getContent()).trim();

    Assert.assertTrue(messageContent.equalsIgnoreCase(CONTENT));
}
```

[github](https://github.com/PalituxD/message-delivery-microservice/blob/message-delivery-application/message-delivery-application/src/test/java/org/justfoolingaround/apps/messagedelivery/services/senders/impl/EmailSenderServiceTest.java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The down votes are probably because this appears to be a "link only" answer in that it doesn't contain the answer and relies on someone following the link(s). Please read about [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).